# How to display files in folder when using PysimpleGUI FileBrowse() function?

Tags: python, user-interface, pysimplegui

Firstly, PySimpleGUI is amazing! However, I cannot figure out how to show all the files in a folder when using folderbrowse() ?

Alternatively, would it be possible to print the filenames in the selected in an outbox box? Please could I get some guidance on this.

[image: example image when using folderbrowse()]
Thanks!

Comment: what did you try? Show your code in question. Did you get error? Show full error message in question.

Comment: added in image to clarify. I am not getting any errors, I would just like to be able to see the files in the folder, which I am unable to. Would it be possible to print the filenames out?

Comment: `folderbrowse()` sould gives you full path to seleced folder and later you should use `os.listdir(folder)` to get names for all files and folders in this folder (but without files in subflders) or `os.walk(folder)` to get for all files and folders in this folder and subloders

Comment: Do you use `FileBrowse()` or `FolderBrowse()`? They are for different use. `FolderBrowse()` is for selecting only folder so it doesn't display files. `FileBrowse()` is for selecting file so it show files and folders. In title you mention `FileBrowse`, in question you mention `FolderBrowser`. I don't use Windows so I can't say which one you have on image. You should show also your code.

Comment: I use FolderBrowse(). Is there any way I can print the items found in the folder onto the GUI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`FileBrowse()` and `FolderBrowse()` are different widgets.

`FolderBrowse()` is for selecting only folder so it doesn't display files.

`FileBrowse()` is for selecting file so it show files and folders (but you can't select folder to get it).

---

`FileBrowse()` gives full path to selected folder and later you should use

- `os.listdir(folder)` to get names for all files and folders in selected folder (but without names in subfolders)
- `os.walk(folder)` to get for all files and folders in this folder and subfolders.
- `glob.glob(pattern)` to get only some names - ie. `glob.glob(f"{folder}/*.png")`

and when you get names then you can print in console or update text in widget.

---

This minimal example display filenames in console after clicking `Submit`

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import os

#help(sg.FolderBrowse)
#help(sg.FileBrowse)

layout = [
    [sg.Input(), sg.FileBrowse('FileBrowse')],
    [sg.Input(), sg.FolderBrowse('FolderBrowse')],
    [sg.Submit(), sg.Cancel()],
]

window = sg.Window('Test', layout)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    #print('event:', event)
    #print('values:', values)
    print('FolderBrowse:', values['FolderBrowse'])
    print('FileBrowse:', values['FileBrowse'])
     
    if event is None or event == 'Cancel':
        break
    
    if event == 'Submit':
        # if folder was not selected then use current folder `.`
        foldername = values['FolderBrowse'] or '.' 

        filenames = os.listdir(foldername)

        print('folder:', foldername)
        print('files:', filenames)
        print("\n".join(filenames))
    
window.close()
```

---

Similar way you can put text in some widget - ie. `MultiLine()` - after pressing `Submit`

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import os

layout = [
    [sg.Input(), sg.FolderBrowse('FolderBrowse')],

    [sg.Submit(), sg.Cancel()],

    [sg.Text('Files')],
    [sg.Multiline(key='files', size=(60,30), autoscroll=True)],

]

window = sg.Window('Test', layout)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
     
    if event is None or event == 'Cancel':
        break
    
    if event == 'Submit':
        foldername = values['FolderBrowse'] or '.'
        filenames = os.listdir(foldername)
        # it uses `key='files'` to access `Multiline` widget
        window['files'].update("\n".join(filenames))
    
window.close()
```

---

**BTW:** system may give filenames in order of creation so you may have to sort them

```
 filenames = sorted(os.listdir(foldername))
```

---

**EDIT:**

To get filenames without `Submit` you may have to use normal `Button` which will execute code with `foldername = PopupGetFolder(..., no_window=True)`.

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import os

layout = [
    [sg.Input(), sg.Button('FolderBrowse')],

    [sg.Text('Files')],
    [sg.Multiline(key='files', size=(60,30), autoscroll=True)],

    [sg.Exit()],    
]

window = sg.Window('Test', layout)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    print(event)
     
    if event is None or event == 'Exit':
        window.close()
        break

    if event == 'FolderBrowse':
        foldername = sg.PopupGetFolder('Select folder', no_window=True)
        if foldername: # `None` when clicked `Cancel` - so I skip it
            filenames = sorted(os.listdir(foldername))
            # it use `key='files'` to `Multiline` widget
            window['files'].update("\n".join(filenames))
```

Comment: Thank you SO much for the detailed answer. I really appreciate it! Have a good day!